# Working on the ferry Naviera Armas - Tenerife -> Huelva

Tags: spain, ferries, canary-islands, tenerife

I'm going from Tenerife to Huelva in a couple of days by Armas ferry. As I went here by Fred Olsen, I'd like to know what to expect from Armas. I have a couple of questions:

1. Can you buy Internet access? If yes, how much is it?
2. Is there a place where you can work on a laptop?
3. Can I go to the garage during the journey or do I need to take all the necessary things with me from the car? If yes, how often if limited?

Comment: Don't have time for an answer, but usually it's (1) Yes, for a fortune at terrible quality; (2) wherever you want, and (3) no.

Answer (score 5):

I traveled by  ferry two weeks ago.

1. Wifi is available to buy if needed and if you have a cabin, then its free. it was ok for light browsing.
2. There are power connectors available, though best places seem to be taken
3. yes i was able to access car deck serval times (there was a posted timetable when it is allowed but i went whenever i needed and that was fine). Just ask the receptionist for access and you can go. My car was on top deck, not sure if it was different for below deck cars.